# aws ec2 instance - permission denied to write to ~/.aws/credentials

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When `ssh` into a aws ec2 linux instance, the user is `ec2-user` by default. Then I need to set aws credentials by writing to `~/.aws/credentials`, but got permission denied. I feel that if I use `sudo` then the `credentials` file would be owned by `root` user, as a result my api server can't read from it.

What's the correct approach to set up aws credentials there?

Comment: The correct way is to use an IAM Role (see below). However, if you _do_ wish to create the credentials file, the easiest way is to run `aws configure`, which will create it for you. It is very strange that you got a _permission denied_ error. I wonder if it was because the `~/.aws` directory did not exist, so it could not create a file within it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you! In my case the `~/.aws` directory was owned by root somehow. Deleting and recreating solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'correct' way to setup the credentials, is to assign a role to the ec2 instance when you create it (or assign them after you create it). That role can be created and assigned to the EC2 instance via the AWS console - there is no need to ssh in and create the credentials there.

See: [Easily Replace or Attach an IAM Role to an Existing EC2 Instance by Using the EC2 Console | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `credentials` file locally, then upload to your ec2 instance.

1. create the `credentials` file locally

```
$ vim credentials
```

2. upload to your ec2 instance

```
$ scp /path/credentials username@servername:/path
```